# Eclipse Slowing Down Continously

Tags: eclipse, performance

First I tell you all my system configuration. I have Intel i7 processor, 16GB RAM and 256GB SSD which is more than sufficient for this situation.

I was previously using eclipse neon. Some days after installation, debug mode becomes too slow that pressing F6 will get to next line after 4 seconds(checked time). Done many suggested steps I found on SO and other websites but nothing worked. So Installed eclipse Oxygen and it ran fine for some days and again the same problem started occurring. Don't know what is causing this.

Steps that I already was taken:

```
1. Modified -Xms and -Xmx parameters in eclipse.ini to update memory restrictions(Xms256m to Xms768m)
2. Uninstalled unused plugins
3. Turned auto update off on new installation also
4. Created new workspaces
5. Used both JDK 1.7 and 1.8 versions
6. Run only eclipse at a time and nothing else
```

One thing that I am noticing is when I start eclipse, it runs perfectly for a certain amount of time(10-15 mins) for the same eclipse project but then starts to slow down.

Please suggest something. Thanks.

Comment: What project is this? Is a build script running in background?

Comment: Its a regular swing project rajesh

Comment: Try to start your Task Manager when first opening eclipse and see if it shows any unusual behaviour when the problem occurs (high CPU / DISK or RAM usage? Have you tried a fresh install of eclipse?

Comment: Yes zeus I checked task manager when it was slow. Nothing unusual I found. Processor usage 3% memory around 28%. Nothing else running not even any background programs. And yes I fresh installed eclipse oxygen.

Comment: How many breakpoints/watchpoints do you have? Do you use conditional breakpoints or tracepoints?

Comment: Thanks P.J. for the edit.

Comment: Hi howlger, this is happening in 2 numbers addition program also. No breakpoints, no GC, no objects, no threads created.

Comment: I think i will not get answer :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

Eclipse was taking java from "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java". I added the path of installed java in eclipse.ini file. I have tested and currently it is working smooth.

Added path:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: didnt help me. :(

Answer (score 5):

Try this....

Please check your JDK & Eclipse Version if its older update.

According to your system config there is enough space to run all the tools.And try some this points:

General > Startup and Shutdown: remove all plugins activated on startup

General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling : Disable spell checking

General > Validation > Suspend all
Window > Customize Perspective > Remove stuff you don’t use or want (shortcut keys are your friends), same for Menu Visibility (how many times have you printed a source file…)

Install/Update > Automatic Updates > Uncheck “Automatically find new updates”

General > Appearance > Uncheck Enable Animations

Stay with the default theme. Unfortunately, anything else makes it really laggy and slow.

Always make garbage collection

tweak garbage collection

-XX:+UseParallelOldGC

Comment: Thanks prakash for suggestion. Maximum of these things I already done and the problem occurs after 10-15 mins. So startup is not affecting anything. Yes I will check the GC tweak this is new I found.

Comment: No mention Chetan Chadha.If all are ok means always clean up your garbage and unwanted memory bez its occur due to lack of program space which slow down your tool.

Comment: Its happening in 2 numbers addition program also. No GC no objects no threads created. :-D

Comment: Here are some further infos on the points mentioned: http://www.nicolasbize.com/blog/7-tips-to-speed-up-eclipse/