# Eclipse Oxygen causes slowdown the whole system

Tags: eclipse, performance, plugins, eclipse-plugin

First of all I am running **Eclipse Oxygen** on a windows system with following configuration which I thing fairly enough.

**System informtion: Intel core(TM) i7 processor, 8GB RAM, 250 SSD storage**

Though initially the Eclipse worked fine, after doing all my configurations it causes to slow down my whole system. I feel like my processor is on fire! Eclipse is sluggish & take a while even to scroll down. Confirm, there is no any other heavy process is running on the system.

Have anybody experience this kind of problem before? Could this be caused by a plug-in or service that I have installed implicitly? If so, how may I diagnosis and turn off such malicious plug-in or demon?

> **Configuration that I have done after installing Eclipse**

- Install few plug-ins such as "SVN Connector", "Oracle Weblogic Server Tools", "Java EE 7 Documentation", "Eclipse Quicksearch" etc.
- Changing to the "Dark Theme"
- General system configurations with relate to a web application.

> **Machine performance while the Eclipse is running**

[CPU utilization is very high while the memory utilization looks okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLiZ1.png)

[Eclipse is the process that cause to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI9rY.png)

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse is a pig.  What do you want us to do about it?  I don't know whether this is a question or just a complaint.

Comment: Disable plugins, close perspectives not in use.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the reply. BTW, I had work with other Eclipse versions for some time but haven't experienced this much worse before. My question is how would I overcome from this problem without uninstalling Eclipse.

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani, Closed other perspectives but no help. Rather disabling all the plugins I just removed some plugins from start up as suggested in Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499036/2465608 & now eclipse work as charm. Now I am searching what plug-in actually caused to this problem. Thanks much for the help.

Comment: Awesome Eclipse !!!

Comment: Be sure to leave an answer with your findings for anyone else who comes across your question.

Comment: Recent versions of Eclipse are using abnormally large amounts of memory. My current version, latest release, will happily swell up to 4 GB if I let it. Previous versions never went much above 750MB-1GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled "Oracle Weblogic Server Tools" plugins at Startup and Shutdown ( **Window > Preferences: General > Startup and Shutdown**) & now eclipse work fine.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

> [Eclipse Quick Search is a fast and easy to use "search as you type" text search tool. Open with Cmd-Shift-L, type your search and see results immediately.](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse)

An index have to be created and updated to offer such service. If you have many files and often switch between branches you may consider to uninstall this plug-in.

See ***Window > Preferences: General > Startup and Shutdown*** for the list of plug-ins that are activated already on startup.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I disabled few plugins at Startup and Shutdown & now eclipse work fine. However, "Eclipse Quick Search" was not in that "Startup and Shutdown" list but I suspect it because of "Oracle Weblogic Server Tools". I am still checking on exactly what plugin causes this problem.

Comment: thanks :), in my case was _Memory analizer UI_ in the _Startup and shutdown_ list.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it is the various validators that get added by web developer plug-ins. Look under "Preferences > Validation" and disable any you do not need. I usually disable HTML and JavaScript because they are CPU intensive as their grammars are not well-formed.